# How do you prevent a Hudson slave from archiving artifacts?

Tags: hudson

It turns out our slaves spend a considerable amount of time moving the archived artifacts back to the master Hudson node. It at least triples the duration of the build. It would be nice if there would be a way to prevent it. However, setting the maximum number of builds to keep doesn't have an influence at all. Is there another way to prevent sending the results back to the central Hudson master?

Note that I actually *don't* have the archive artifacts option checked. However, the slave is still 'archiving' whatever it finds to the master:

```
[HUDSON] Archiving .../pom.xml to .../pom.xml
[HUDSON] Archiving .../...-0.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar to .../...-0.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

... with the second path in every line always being a location on the master. Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Could you clarify what type of Hudson job this is?   Freestyle, matrix or maven2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maven jobs have an option for not archiving artifacts in the advanced options of the Maven section - that is, separate from the "Archive Artifacts" publisher. By default, the Maven jobs will archive the Maven artifacts of a module automatically, regardless of the "Archive Artifacts" publisher settings. The advanced option for Maven projects was added a couple months ago, if I remember correctly.

Comment: The issue tracking that feature is http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-4593

Answer (score 1):

It sounds that you don't need the archived artifacts at all. So check the `archive artifacts` option for your jobs. If it is unchecked and it still copies the artifacts to the master to scrap them right away, open a bug report with Hudson.

If you need some, play around with the advanced options for `archive artifacts`. They offer an include as well as an exclude option.

Comment: Exactly. You could you uncheck "archive artifacts", but then use one of the "move some files to somewhere else" plugins (can't remember any names offhand) if do you want to archive them locally on the slave.

Comment: I will update the original description. (Copying structured text in here doesn't work all that well.) However, I never had the archive artifacts property checked, but still got the archiving behaviour.

Comment: It turns out that even when archive artifacts is checked and (using an exclusion pattern) all archiving is disabled, it still seems to be archiving.